# Unable to install ANY package from pip; wheel failed to build

Tags: python, installation, pip, setup.py, python-wheel

Whenever I try to install any package from pip(`pip install --upgrade bottle-websocket`for example)

I always get the same error, wheel fails to build, I have already tried to upgrade setuptools and wheel and pip, everything, but still I get the same error.

```
 pip install --upgrade bottle-websocket
WARNING: Skipping /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pytube-12.1.3-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
Collecting bottle-websocket                                                                                                          
  Using cached bottle-websocket-0.2.9.tar.gz (2.0 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting bottle (from bottle-websocket)
  Using cached bottle-0.12.25-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting gevent-websocket (from bottle-websocket)
  Using cached gevent_websocket-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: gevent in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket) (22.10.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: bottle-websocket
  Building wheel for bottle-websocket (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  � python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  ? exit code: 1
  ??> [41 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      creating build/lib/bottle_websocket
      copying bottle_websocket/plugin.py -> build/lib/bottle_websocket
      copying bottle_websocket/server.py -> build/lib/bottle_websocket
      copying bottle_websocket/__init__.py -> build/lib/bottle_websocket
      /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer, pypa/build or
              other standards-based tools.
      
              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      installing to build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel
      running install
      running install_lib
      creating build/bdist.linux-aarch64
      creating build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel
      creating build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/bottle_websocket
      copying build/lib/bottle_websocket/plugin.py -> build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/bottle_websocket
      copying build/lib/bottle_websocket/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/bottle_websocket
      copying build/lib/bottle_websocket/server.py -> build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/bottle_websocket
      running install_egg_info
      running egg_info
      writing bottle_websocket.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to bottle_websocket.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to bottle_websocket.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to bottle_websocket.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'bottle_websocket.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      writing manifest file 'bottle_websocket.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      Copying bottle_websocket.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/bottle_websocket-0.2.9-py3.11.egg-info
      error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build/bdist.linux-aarch64/wheel/bottle_websocket-0.2.9-py3.11.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bottle-websocket
  Running setup.py clean for bottle-websocket                                                                                        
Failed to build bottle-websocket
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bottle-websocket, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

This is the error

Comment: python pip install pyproject.toml-based

Comment: Are you running this command with `sudo`? Have you tried using `pip install --user`?

Comment: @toyotaSupra i don't think that will help

Comment: @FlyingTeller no i have tried `pip install auto-py-to-exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work out, the answer was simple, I had to do it with root privileges, I typed `sudo -i` and typed in the installation command and it worked!

Answer (score -2):

Try to run the `pip install cmake` command and make sure you have the wheel, setuptools, and pip packages installed and upgraded.

If that doesn't work, try using `pip3` instead of `pip`, or if it is a problem with `pip` (maybe it is not installed correctly), try using `python -m`, like this:

`python -m pip install cmake`
or
`python3 -m pip install cmake`

Comment: Why would this be related to cmake?

Comment: I did, that didn't help